# error when trying to run linked list c program

Tags: c, error-handling

I am new to programming.So the problem here is that when i want to execute the following program,but it is just showing that the program have stopped working.I have no idea what is wrong with the code because there is no compilation error.Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ppl
{
    char name[30];
    struct ppl *next;
};

main()
{

    struct ppl *student1, *student2, *student3, *student4, *temp, *ptr, *x;
    struct ppl *head = NULL;
    int no;

    head = (struct ppl *)malloc(sizeof(struct ppl));
    student1 = (struct ppl *)malloc(sizeof(struct ppl));
    student2 = (struct ppl *)malloc(sizeof(struct ppl));
    student3 = (struct ppl *)malloc(sizeof(struct ppl));
    student4 = (struct ppl *)malloc(sizeof(struct ppl));

    head->next = student1;
    strcpy(student1->name, "Aizar");

    student1->next = student2;
    strcpy(student2->name, "Chandi");

    student2->next = student3;
    strcpy(student3->name, "Faizul");

    student3->next = student4;
    strcpy(student4->name, "Joshua");
    student4->next = NULL;

    ptr = head;
    while (ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr = (struct ppl *)malloc(sizeof(struct ppl));
        ptr = ptr->next;
        printf("Name list : %s \n", ptr);

    };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: I don't think you intend to be allocating inside the while loop. Once you call malloc (inside the while), you've taken ptr completely outside the list.

Comment: what do you want from this program to do ? printing students names ??

Comment: Yes..I want to display the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was inside the while loop. Try this:

```
while(ptr->next != NULL)
{
 ptr = ptr->next; 
    printf("Name list : %s \n", ptr );

};
```

PS: `ptr` doesn't need separate memory allocation. It will point to the memory locations pointed by the pointers which are assigned to it (in the `while` loop).

Answer (score 0):

**Note** : ***`don't give me fish teach me how to fish`***

***Some comments :***

```
 ptr = head; // here ptr has the value of head
    while (ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr = (struct ppl *)malloc(sizeof(struct ppl)); // ptr loses the value of head and takes new value given by malloc
        ptr = ptr->next; // ptr -> next is null so ptr becomes null
        printf("Name list : %s \n", ptr); // generally if you want to print pointers use %p not %s 

    };
```

***Some indications :***

1. I think you want to print students names not pointers .
2. no need to allocate memory for ptr , because before while loop it takes the value of head .

***Now your turn to correct your code according to your needs .***

Happy Coding :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the following.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ppl
{
    char name[30];
    struct ppl *next;
};

int main( void )
{

    struct ppl *student1, *student2, *student3, *student4, *temp;
    struct ppl *head = NULL;

    student1 = (struct ppl *)malloc( sizeof( struct ppl ) );
    student2 = (struct ppl *)malloc( sizeof( struct ppl ) );
    student3 = (struct ppl *)malloc( sizeof( struct ppl ) );
    student4 = (struct ppl *)malloc( sizeof( struct ppl ) );

    strcpy( student1->name, "Aizar" );
    student1->next = student2;

    strcpy( student2->name, "Chandi" );
    student2->next = student3;

    strcpy( student3->name, "Faizul" );
    student3->next = student4;

    strcpy( student4->name, "Joshua" );
    student4->next = NULL;

    head = student1;

    for ( temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next )
    {
        printf( "Student Name: %s \n", temp->name );
    }

    while ( head )
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free( temp );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Student Name: Aizar 
Student Name: Chandi 
Student Name: Faizul 
Student Name: Joshua
```

As for your code then this loop

```
while (ptr->next != NULL)
{
    ptr = (struct ppl *)malloc(sizeof(struct ppl));
    ptr = ptr->next;
    printf("Name list : %s \n", ptr);

};
```

does not make sense.

Also you need not to allocate a separate node for the head. The head should be a pointer to the first allocated "student".

Take into account that function main in C shall have return type `int`